# How do I merge the following 4 SPs to make it one or may be 2?

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server

```
ALTER PROC [Schema1].[SetDefaultBAdd]
(
    @UserAddDetailID bigint,
        @IsB bit
)
AS
BEGIN
    UPDATE Schema1.UserAddDetails

SET IsDefault = 1 WHERE UserAddDetailID=@UserAddDetailID AND IsB=@IsB

END
--------------------------------------------------------------------------
ALTER PROC [Schema1].[SetNotDefaultBAdd]
(
    @UserID bigint,
    @IsB bit

)
AS
BEGIN
    UPDATE Schema1.UserAddDetails SET IsDefault = 0 WHERE UserID=@UserID AND IsB=@IsB

END


--------------------------------------------------------------------------

ALTER PROC [Schema1].[SetDefaultShAdd]
(
    @UserAddDetailID bigint,
        @IsSh bit
)
AS
BEGIN
    UPDATE Schema1.UserAddDetails

SET IsDefault = 1 WHERE UserAddDetailID=@UserAddDetailID AND IsSh=@IsSh

END

--------------------------------------------------------------------------



ALTER PROC [Schema1].[SetNotDefaultShAdd]
(
    @UserID bigint,
    @IsSh bit

)
AS
BEGIN
    UPDATE Schema1.UserAddDetails SET IsDefault = 0 WHERE UserID=@UserID AND IsSh=@IsSh

END
```

Comment: do you really even *need* stored procedures for this, given your using ASP.NET, and all your doing is updating table a based on value b? Why not just use a classic ADO.NET call, and you can dynamically create the query in the code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want just one proc:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [Schema1].[SuperDuperProcedure]
(
  @UserID             bigint = NULL,
  @UserAddDetailID    bigint = NULL,
  @IsB                bit,
  @IsSh               bit
)
AS
BEGIN
  UPDATE
    Schema1.UserAddDetails
  SET
    IsDefault = 0
  WHERE
    UserID = @UserID
    AND
    (IsB = @IsB OR IsSh = @IsSh)

  UPDATE
    Schema1.UserAddDetails
  SET
    IsDefault = 1
  WHERE
    UserAddDetailID = @UserAddDetailID
    AND
    (IsB = @IsB OR IsSh = @IsSh)
END
```

Comment: I am not sure if this is wat I want..I mean IsDefault's value is not being passed as parameter when SP is called..it is being set in the SP itself based on other parameters values..u hv written SET
 IsDefault = @IsDefault...IsDefault is not to be passed from code
to the SP

Comment: @Serenity - I've updated the answer with your additional requirement.